# How to wait for element to be fully rendered to execute CSS transition?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, transition

I have a button with a click event listener that calls 2 different functions. The first function fades out a div by adding a class that triggers a CSS transition to opacity 0, then the innerHTML is changed, then the class is removed and opacity fades back to 1.

The second function creates and img element, adds it to the div, and then adds a class to the img that's a CSS scale transition. So what it should look like is: click -> div fades out -> div fades back in with new content -> image appears and grows in size.

In order for it to work properly, all these events have to happen in succession. The only way I have managed to make it work is with setTimeouts, which is really not the best way. I've tried promises, transitionend event listeners, requestAnimationFrame, and none of those seem to work. Either the img doesn't load or it loads already scaled and the transition is absent. Can anyone please help me figure out how to set up these events so that each one is awaiting the completion of the last before triggering? Thank you!

Pseudocode:

```
function resetDiv() {
         const div = document.querySelector('#div');
         div.classList.add('cssFadeout');

            div.ontransitionend = () => {
                div.innerHTML = `${text literal HTML stored in a variable}`;
                div.classList.remove('fadeOut');
        }

function generateImg() {

            const newImg = document.createElement('img');
            newImg.src = 'img.png';
            newImg.id = 'newImg';
            div.appendChild(newImg);

            document.querySelector('#newImg').classList.add('cssScale')
}

button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    resetDiv();

    generateImg();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery:

> $(()=>{ callback })

Or vanilla js:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
```

});

here is the mdn documentation for DOMContentLoaded
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Answer (score 0):

'So what you need here is a reflow of the page which is going to force the 're-render' the layout.

A way to do that iswith el.offsetWidth. 
Basically what it happens, for example if you would place it here:

```
button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    resetDiv();

    el.offsetWidth

    generateImg();

});
```

is that when offsetWidth is called, JavaScript is 're-running' to check the width of the element in that moment even though the element's width didn't change, so the first function runs, the first animation is done, JavaScript is checking now for the offsetWidth then does the second animation.

So, declare a global variable that you use in resetDiv, maybe the querySelector of the 'div' and check it's width in between the two functions.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately it's not working for me, I still just get an already scaled image. I think it's running the scale transformation before the image is fully loaded in the DOM, it's the only explanation I can come up with for the behaviour. Like I said, it works if I set a timeout. But thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion based on your pseudocode:

```
function resetDiv() {
    const div = document.querySelector('#div');
    div.classList.add('cssFadeout');

    div.ontransitionend = () => {
        div.innerHTML = `${text literal HTML stored in a variable}`;
        sky.classList.remove('fadeOut');
        // wait for the transition triggered above to end and then call the other function
        // also remove the call to generateImg() from the click-handler
        sky.ontransitionend = generateImg;
    };
}
```